# Unable to reset password from apex code using System.resetPassword()

Tags: apex, email, permissions

I have created a user from community. And from that community i need to reset password by Apex code.

Right now i am trying call `System.resetpassword()` method to do this but no success.

Exception is:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: portal user email settings are not available

Exception seems self descriptive but I need to reset password of user programatically. Is it possible and in which scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also get this error and when I went to community and allow the profile on community. 
This profile which you are giving to user. and I am using web service in my context.

I think this wll help you.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve a similar problem with System.resetPassword() by ensuring that this call is made from a class declared WITHOUT SHARING.  The reason it works is because this class is executing in the System Context with elevated permissions.

```
/**
 * An apex page controller that exposes the site forgot password functionality
 * but performs a hard reset on the existing password to prevent further logins without a reset
 */
public with sharing class ForgotPasswordHardResetController {
    // Username is set by the Visual Force page
    public String username {get; set;}   

    public ForgotPasswordHardResetController() {}

    public PageReference forgotPassword() {         
        // Reset Password Requires the Userid
        try {
          List<User> matchingUsers = [SELECT id,username,email from User where UserName = :username];
            if (matchingUsers.size()>0) {
               User currentUser = matchingUsers[0];

               // Method is delegated to another class which uses without sharing to workaround permissions
               new ResetHelper().resetPassword(currentUser);

               PageReference pr = Page.ForgotPasswordConfirm;
               pr.setRedirect(true);
               System.debug('Password reset initiated');
               return pr;       
            } else {
               ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Username not found');
               ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
               return null; 
            }
        } catch (System.Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Unexpected error');
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,ex.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }


    }

    /**
     * Helper class must be declared without sharing to force it to run in System Context
     **/ 
    public without sharing class ResetHelper {
        public void resetPassword(User currentUser) {
            System.resetPassword(currentUser.id,false); // force immediate password reset, no email
            Site.forgotPassword(currentUser.Username);  // repeat the reset and send the templated community email
        }
    }
}
```